# Japanese spelling and grammar checks solution

Tags: discussion

I need a way to spellcheck/grammar check Japanese text in Web. Are there any existing browser solutions (plugins) or API, that could help achieve that?

I've investigated this topic and existing solutions do not satisfy our needs because they work quite strange. Solution, that I checked was https://languagetool.org/, which claims to check the spelling and grammar on Japanese text, however, it always says that the text is valid, even if it is not. Also I checked https://www.stars21.com/spelling/japanese/ which is using Yahoo Star - it works fine but has no API or browser plugin.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: There are checkers for professional writing, but few are for learners. This seems it, but the service apparently gone offline... http://www.jnlp.org/SNOW/S24

Comment: Thank you for the link! Yes, sadly but seems https://app.jnlp.org/gec/ doesn't work.

BTW are any spellchecking dictionaries for Japanese?

Comment: If you have MS Word, it has a quite solid spellcheck built in for Japanese.

Comment: Yes, it works. But idea is to use spellchecking in a browser (like browser plugin) or at least like web API.